# Liferay Workflow With Activiti Plugin

Tags: workflow, liferay

I am using `Liferay Activiti Workflow Plugin` to implement workflow. The `Activiti Workflow Plugin` is a hook. The plugin is working fine. But I have following issues:

1. How can I make `User` object for Liferay workflow enabled?
2. How can I make `Custom Entity` which has table definition for it in separate schema from 'lportal' Liferay workflow enabled?

I have read this [article](http://www.cignex.com/articles/applying-advanced-workflow-custom-assets-liferay-6).

Here it describes one step where we it says to add in `liferay-portlet.xml` following entry:

```
<workflow-handler>com.liferay.workflow.ArticleWorkflowHandler</workflow-handler>
```

But I am using hook which does not have `liferay-portlet.xml` file. So how should I proceed, what would be the steps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

it's better structure your project modular and define your custom entity as an asset in the different liferay plugin than Activiti Liferay Hook. to do this:

1. Create a new portlet project and define your Custom Entity in it,
2. Then you can modify liferay-portlet.xml and point your portlet to your workflow handler.

also notice if in this way you need to call Activiti Jars. you can move them from lib directory of Liferay Activiti Hook to the global lib directory(in Tomcat it place here: ${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib ).

but if you really need to define your custom entities in the Liferay Activiti Project itself, first add a portlet to it. remember that a Liferay project can consist of several liferay plugin(such as hook portlet...). to do this. it's better to import its source to an IDE like eclipse then create a portlet on it and do what you want